# If $\tan A=2$, find the possible values of $\csc A$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan A=2$, find the possible values of $\csc A$.

Can someone please show me thorough steps as to how to do this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\cot(A) = 1/2$, then use $\csc^{2}(A) = 1+ \cot^{2}(A)$ to get $\csc(A)= \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{5}{4}}$. Depending on increasing level of trig. sophistication the answer is $\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{4}}$ or $\pm \sqrt{\dfrac{5}{4}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using identity, $\csc^2 A=1+\cot^2 A$ and $\cot A=\dfrac{1}{\tan A}$ gives $\csc A=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{4}}$

But here we used $\csc^2$ to compute $\csc$ which may give us Spurious Solutions. So we need to verify which solutions satisfy the necessary condition given below:

Since $\tan A=2>0\implies A$ lies in $1^{st},3^{rd}$ quadrant and in $1^{st},3^{rd}$ $\csc$ takes both positive and negative values $(+$ in $1^{st}$ and $- $ in $3^{rd})$ .Therefore, $\csc A=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{4}}$